# No records getting while execute two table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Why is it not getting cross product type records ?

If table **test2** have a record with **testName**.
and table **test1** have no any record.

```
 select *from test2
 column name  : name
 column value : testName

 select *from test1
 column name  : id
 column value : 

select *From test1,test2 
id     name 

*no any records
```

**I want record like this.**

```
id     name 
null   testName
```

Comment: add dbms tag here

Comment: You are doing a cross join here. What is you goal?

Answer (score 1):

Using full join with a condition that will always evaluate to `true` will get you the desired results:

Create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
create table test1
(
    id int
)

create table test2
(
    name varchar(10)
)  

insert into test2 values ('testName')
```

The query:

```
select *
from test1
full join test2 on 1=1
```

Results:

```
id  name
NULL    testName
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to fetch the records that may or may not exist in another table:

```
 select * 
 From test2 b
 left join test1 a ON a.value = b.value
```

Comment: Thanks for response! Let me check

Comment: there is no `name` column in test2

Comment: Updated please check.

Comment: It's not getting correct, test1 can be no records or many records.

Comment: Sorry, we have to use the table first where value always exist in this case. it's corrected please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.name 
FROM test2 AS t2 LEFT JOIN 
    test1 AS t1 ON 1=1
WHERE t2.name LIKE 'testName'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test1)
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Table test2 have no Column 'id'

Comment: Thanks for your quick response